# why ng-repeat not work in directive using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use directive in mu page ..I am trying to send data from controller to directive .I am trying to display data using **ng-repeat**.

here is I am applying the ng-repeat .

```
  <div class="container">
            <!--Row with two equal columns-->
            <div class="row " ng-repeat='d in data'>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="demo-content">{{d.Location}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="demo-content bg-alt description-ellipse">{{d.description}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="demo-content bg-alt">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default view-now-button">VIEW NOW</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I make a **directive** like this

```
.directive('listComponent', function() {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
              data:'='
            },
            templateUrl: 'list.html',
            link: function(s, e, a) {

            }
        }

    })
```

I am sending data like that

**data:'='**  and from here   `<list-component data='h.data'></list-component>`

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/Q0GQC2Pik7m25HxQIW8H?p=preview

Comment: You could pass data as `data='h.data.jobs'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
<div class="row " ng-repeat='d in data.jobs'>
```

in `list.html`

Or, as per comment:

```
<list-component data='h.data.jobs'></list-component>
```

Updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SkQ8HW72TCloGUJpxOB2?p=preview)